# How to lock a user from log in after expiration date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have created 3 devise user models with `rails generate devise MODEL`, admin, user1, user2.

Also I have created a Subscription scaffold(title, description, price, expiration:integer). Where user1 can purchase a subscription via a cart and then go to the checkout process.

My question is, how can I implement an expiration date and lock the user from login after the expiration date?
And is the following approach correct?

I’m trying set the expiration date with this:

```
def set_expiration_date
    self.expiration =  current_user1.created_at + Subscription.expiration
end
```

And even though I’m using the following code in application controller:

```
def current_user1
  return unless session[:user1_id]
  @current_user1 ||= User.find(session[:user1_id])
end
```

an error appears undefined local variable or method `current_user1’

My plan after I get the above code working is to try to define expired and active subscription.

```
 def expired
  set_expiration_date.to_i <= 0 
 end  

 def active
  set_expiration_date.to_i > 0  
 end
```

In order to lock the user from log in I intend to use this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.is_a?(User1) && resource.expired?
    sign_out resource
    expired_user1_path
  else
 super
  end
end
```

Comment: You could use a before_filter and check for self.expiration.If expired logout.

Comment: https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension Have you taken a look at this? Disclaimer: I have not, just googled and saw it.